# How to extract the p.value and estimate from cor.test()?

Tags: r, for-loop, p-value

I perform cor.test for a dataset in a for loop, but I don't know how to extract the information like estimate and tau from my test.

Before performing for loop in the dataset, The cor.test() function returns as follows:

`cor.test(armpit$Corynebacterium.1, armpit$Staphylococcus.1, alterantive="two-sided", method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)`

[return result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaGlD.png)

Here is my code for performing for loop. Now I want to extract estimate and tau from my test.

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  for (j in 1:8) {
    if (j != i)
    cor.test( as.numeric(unlist(armpit[i])),
        as.numeric(unlist(armpit[j])), alterantive="two-sided",
        method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
   }
}
```

I have check the similar question from

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577135/how-to-extract-the-p-value-and-estimate-from-cor-test-in-a-data-frame)

Then I change my code as:

```
estimates = numeric(50)
pvalues = numeric(50)
for (i in 1:8) {
  for (j in 1:8) {
    if (j != i)
    cor.test( as.numeric(unlist(armpit[i])),
        as.numeric(unlist(armpit[j])), alterantive="two-sided",
         method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
    estimates[i] = cor.test$estimate
    pvalues[i]= cor.test$p-value
   }
   }
```

But it returns:

`Error in cor.test$estimate : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Could anyone offer me some help about how to extract estimate and tau value from cor.test() function in a for loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: h@hugh sas the correct answer.  Just a little conceptual clarification: when you just do `cor.test(...)` the answer is dumped to the console.  That's fine for interactive work. But when writing a script or function, you need to capture the output that would normally go to the console, and that's what @hugh answer does.

Comment: btw `psych` package has a function `corr.test` that allows you to pass dataframes / matrices rather than vectors (basically same code as you have but saves reinventing)

Comment: Thank you @BryanHanson , but the following problem is that I tried the code and it returns ` Error: object 'cor_test' not found` , then I tried to add the line of code to pre-define the cor_test : cor_test=list( 50 ), then it returns: Error in estimates[i] = cor_test$estimate : replacement has length zero . I checked online but not found the solution? Do you have idea about this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must have a small error of some kind.  Why don't you edit your original answer to include the commands you are using to call the function that @hugh gave in his answer (note: `alternative` is spelled wrong there and in your original function, so correct that).  Also, maybe you have a "stale" workspace with left over variables.  Start a new R session and then test things.  Finally, it's much easier for us to test things with a small sample of your original data, so add to your edit the results of `dput(head(armpit))` (just paste it in).

Comment: Thank you Dear @BryanHanson . I have double check code and no mistake found. I have also restart the RStudio but it appears the same error. I tried to add `dput(head(armpit))`, and error is the same.   I have shared my code and dataset in the dropbox, and here is the [dataset link ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcvv8ukl8mmkfrk/armpit.RData?dl=0)   and          [my code link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iluxaz39gd30dn9/mycode.R?dl=0) . I appreciate if you have time to check my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found it, we should have seen it earlier.  The `if (j != i)` statement needs to have brackets around everything that should be done if the statement is true.  With the particular formatting you had, R was not parsing it correctly.  I couldn't get your data, so I made some up (which will test random rows against random columns).  This works:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(8*8), ncol = 8) # made up test data
estimates = numeric(50)
pvalues = numeric(50)
for (i in 1:8) {
  for (j in 1:8) {
    if (j != i) { # need this bracket
        cor_test <-  cor.test(M[i,], M[,j],
             alternative="two.sided",
              method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
        estimates[i] = cor_test$estimate
        pvalues[i]= cor_test$p.value
        } # and this bracket
    }
    }
estimates
pvalues
```

EDIT: alternative version to store all results in a data frame.

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(8*8), ncol = 8) # made up test data

ans <- data.frame(i = rep(NA, 64), j = rep(NA, 64), estimate = rep(NA, 64), pvalue = rep(NA, 64))
cnt <- 1
for (i in 1:8) {
  for (j in 1:8) {
    if (j != i) {
        cor_test <-  cor.test(M[i,], M[,j], alternative="two.sided", method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
        ans[cnt,1] <- i
        ans[cnt,2] <- j
        ans[cnt,3] <- cor_test$estimate
        ans[cnt,4] <- cor_test$p.value
        cnt <- cnt + 1
        }
    }
    }

ans <- na.omit(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you @Bryan Hanson . Sorry that I have also an follow-up problem that I want to store the output values as an array [just like this image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w0hxvyc3saze12/2015-12-26_222215.png?dl=0), and my preliminary code is here,  [my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/obi1x76nfb3t1qq/mycode_v2.R?dl=0) . but I don't know how to figure out the logic of storing the output of double loop  in an array, so I think the code has the logic problem. Could you help me to check this code or offer me some hint about storing the output of double loop  in an array?Thank you again.

Comment: here is to add my dataset [my dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pcvv8ukl8mmkfrk/armpit.RData?dl=0)

Comment: What is the objective?  Do you really want to store it that way, or do you want to print it out for inspection?  Your results could be stored several different ways depending upon what you want as a final result.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a simple data frame containing all the results.  If you need something more complex than that, I suggest you start a new question as we are off topic now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply@Bryan Hanson  ! My objective is not to print it out for inspection. Since my code is to check the correlation between`armpit[i] ` and any other  `armpit[j] ` for which `i != j ` , now this problem is solved, and next my objective is to record the **estimate values** and corresponding **P-values** for each`armpit[i] ~ armpit[j]  (if i !=j)`,  but without assigning the output values to an array,  `estimates[i] ` will just return a series of estimate values as an vector, and It is not clear. Do I make my question clear, and if so, do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Thank you @Bryan Hanson, really very very appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

`cor.test` returns a list. You can create an object to capture this list:

```
cor_test <- cor.test( as.numeric(unlist(armpit[i])), as.numeric(unlist(armpit[j])), alterantive="two-sided", method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
```

Then use `cor_test` afterwards with `$` to access each element of the list:

```
estimates[i] = cor_test$estimate  
pvalues[i]= cor_test$p.value  # note the ., not the -
```

The original error is pretty arcane, so it's understandable you were confused about this. You wrote `cor.test$estimate`, which asks R to access the `estimate` component of the `cor.test` ***function***, not the result of the test.

```
estimates = numeric(50)
pvalues = numeric(50)
for (i in 1:8) {
  for (j in 1:8) {
    if (j != i)
    cor_test <- 
      cor.test( as.numeric(unlist(armpit[i])),
        as.numeric(unlist(armpit[j])), alterantive="two-sided",
         method="kendall", exact=FALSE, continuity=TRUE)
    estimates[i] = cor_test$estimate
    pvalues[i]= cor_test$p.value
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Hugh   your answer is very reasonable and helpful, but the following problem is that I tried the code and it returns             ` Error: object 'cor_test' not found` ,                then I tried to add the line of code to pre-define the cor_test :     `cor_test=list( 50 )`,              then it returns:                                       `Error in estimates[i] = cor_test$estimate : replacement has length zero ` .                        I checked online but not found the solution? Do you have idea about this? Thank you again.