# Extracting Estimate and P-value from multiple cor.test() results in R

Tags: r, function, lapply, readxl

I have an Excel workbook with 54 sheets. Each sheet represents one country and is an 17 x 11 matrix where rows are years and columns are economic variables.

I can bring the Excel workbook into R using the **readxl** package.

```
sheet_list <- lapply(1:54, function(i) read_excel("FDI-vs-variables.xlsx", sheet = i, na="NA"))
```

My data now exists as a list of dataframes, *sheet_list*, where each dataframe represents one sheet of my workbook.

Next, I want to run a correlation test on whichever two variables I'd like, across all the sheets/dataframes.

For example, the third column in all the sheets/dataframes is GDP and the eighth column is % of population that is malnourished. I can write a function that grabs those respective columns in a sheet/dataframe and runs a correlation test using that data.

```
dfCorTest <- function(df){
  rslt <- cor.test(df[[3]],df[[8]], method="kendall",use="pairwise")
  return(rslt)
}
```

I then use **lapply** to apply that function to every sheet/dataframe in my list of 54 sheets/dataframes.

```
cor_results <- lapply(sheet_list, dfCorTest)
```

This results in a list of lists, *cor_results*, detailing the results of 54 different **cor.test** runs.

How do I extract just the correlation estimate (tau) and the p-value from this list of lists?

I know you can call the specific results of **cor.test** using `$estimate` and `$p.value`, and I can do so within the *cor_results* list like so:

```
cor_results[[1]]$estimate
cor_results[[1]]$p.value
cor_results[[2]]$estimate
cor_results[[2]]$p.value
...and so on
```

But what's the efficient way of doing this? Ideally, I'd like to be able to write out to text file where output looks something like

```
SheetNo    Estimate    P-value
1          3.33        0.054
2          -2.76       0.889
...        ...         ...
54         1.23        0.007
```

I know there was a similar question asked in [How to extract...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471573/how-to-extract-the-p-value-and-estimate-from-cor-test), but they used **for loops** rather than **lapply** to run multiple correlation tests and I can't seem to work out the equivalent code.

**UPDATE/EDIT**

Answer suggested by user *Parfait* below worked (thank you!). Amending what was returned by the function and a combo of **sapply** and **transpose**:

```
dfCorTest <- function(df){
  rslt <- cor.test(df[[3]], df[[8]], method="kendall", use="pairwise")

  return(c(estimate = rslt$estimate,
           p.value = rslt$p.value))
}

cor_results <- t(sapply(sheet_list, dfCorTest))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `sapply` for a matrix output (i.e., **s**implified version) of your correlation results with adjustment of the return object and a transpose, `t()`, at the end:

```
dfCorTest <- function(df){
  rslt <- cor.test(df[[3]], df[[8]], method="kendall", use="pairwise")

  return(c(estimate = rslt$estimate,
           p.value = rslt$p.value))
}

cor_results <- t(sapply(sheet_list, dfCorTest))
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/TCL5748)