# Getting the significance from cor.test's into a vector

Tags: r, data.table, correlation

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(
"ID country year Event_A Event_B
4   BEL   2002  0   1
5   BEL   2002  0   1
6   NLD   2002  1   1
7   NLD   2006  1   0
8   NLD   2006  1   1
9   GBR   2001  0   1
10  GBR   2001  0   0
11  GBR   2001  0   1
12  GBR   2007  1   1
13  GBR   2007  1   1",
header = TRUE)
```

I can get the correlation of `Event_A` with the other numerical columns by doing the following:

```
numcols <- names(Filter(is.numeric,DT)) 
corr_y <- DT[, data.table(var=numcols, cor(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget("Event_A")],use= 
"pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))]
```

I would however also like to have a vector with the significance, say `sign_corr_y`, of the correlation.

I know that `cor.test` has the significance but the following does not work:

```
sign_corr_y<- DT[, data.table(var=numcols, cor.test(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget("Event_A")],use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))]
```

Gives the error: `Error in cor.test.default(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget("Event_A")],  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length`

And also this does not work:

```
sign_corr_y<- DT[, data.table(var=numcols, cor.test$p.value(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget("Event_A")],use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))]
```

I have looked at what they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34471573/how-to-extract-the-p-value-and-estimate-from-cor-test), but I don't know how to incorporate the `unlist` into my data.table solution.

Could someone lend a hand?

EDIT: I am still getting an error with my actual data (used inside a function):

Based on @IceCreamToucan 's  answer I have tried:

```
  corr_y_sign <- DT[, data.table(var=numcols, sapply(Filter(is.numeric, DT), function(x) cor.test(x, DT[, mget(corvar)], use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson")$p.value))]
  corr_y_sign <- sapply(Filter(is.numeric, DT), function(x) cor.test(x, DT[, mget(corvar)], use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson")$p.value)
```

But I always get the error: `Error in cor.test.default(x, DT[, mget(corvar)], use = "pairwise.complete.obs",  : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length`

Comment: Does this syntax work: `test <- cor.test(VAR1, VAR2) test$p.value
[1] 2.30034e-05`

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Just a vector of the significances of the correlations of `Event_A` with each numerical column. Just like `corr_y` is a vector of the correlations of `Event_A` with each numerical column.

Comment: What about `sapply(Filter(is.numeric, DT), function(x) cor.test(x, DT[, Event_A])$p.value)`

Comment: That works! I had already started to tinker with `lapply` but I could not figure out how to specify `x`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I have been trying to expand you approach in a similar fashion to: `DT[, data.table(var=numcols, cor(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget("Event_A")],use= 
"pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))]` But I keep ending up with the same error : `'x' and 'y' must have the same length`. Could you perhaps help me out with the syntax? (ps. I am using `mget` because I am using it inside a function and `Event_A` is specified as `"Event_A"`).

Comment: you also might consider using the `cor.ci` function from the `psych` package, which automatically gives you an estimate of a correlation coefficient and a p value for each estimate (plus a confidence interval)

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you're using `cor` without any apply function and I'm using `cor.test` inside `sapply`. The code I showed should work the same if you replace `Event_A` with `get('Event_A')`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I just cannot seem to get it to work. Just to make sure we are on the same line the `corr_y <- DT[, data.table(var=numcols, cor(.SD[, mget(numcols)], .SD[, mget(corvar)],use= 
"pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson"))]` works within the function I have.  I have adapted your function to `corr_y_sign <-sapply(Filter(is.numeric, DT), function(x) cor.test(x, DT[, mget(corvar)], use= "pairwise.complete.obs", method= "pearson")$p.value)` to deal with the NA's but I still get the same error.

Comment: I think that's just because you're using `mget`, which is for multiple variables. Since there's only one, use `get` instead.

Comment: You were right! Again, thanks a lot!